# UIActivityIndicator on UITableViewCell is not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a problem regarding UIActivity Indicator , I m implementing Activity indicator on UITableView Cell but it is not working. My code is as follows, if can solve it please tell me the mistake I m doing in it.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];


    if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0) 
    {
       if ([indexPath row]==[FriendSuggestion count]) 
       {
        int cursor=[Constants getCursorForKey:@"friendList_cursor"];

        if (cursor!=0) 
        {
         [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] addSubview:indicator];
         [indicator setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 25, 37, 37)];
         [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startAnimating) toTarget:indicator withObject:nil];


         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [self loadingMore:indexPath :indicator :cursor];
         });


        }else
         isNoMoreData=YES;

        [tableView reloadData];
       }
    }
    else
    {
       if ([indexPath row]==[popularSuggestion count]) 
       {
        int cursor=[Constants getCursorForKey:@"popularList_cursor"];  

          if (cursor!=0) 
          {
           [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] addSubview:indicator];
           [indicator setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 25, 37, 37)];
           [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startAnimating) toTarget:indicator withObject:nil];


           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self loadingMore:indexPath :indicator :cursor];
           });


          }else
           isNoMoreData=YES;

        [tableView reloadData];
       }
    }
}


-(void)loadingMore:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath:(UIActivityIndicatorView*)indicator:(int)cursor
{

 NSLog(@"loading more called ...");

 if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0) 
 {

            isNoMoreData=NO;
            NSArray *nextArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
            nextArray=[Constants getFriendsSuggestionsStr:cursor];

            for (NSDictionary *dic in nextArray) {
             [FriendSuggestion addObject:dic];
            }
 }else
 {     
             isNoMoreData=NO;
             NSArray *nextArray=[[NSArray alloc] init];
             nextArray=[Constants getPopularSuggestionsStr:cursor];

             for (NSDictionary *dic in nextArray) {
              [popularSuggestion addObject:dic];
             }
 }

 [table reloadData];
 [indicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: please remove the following from the code 
 [table reloadData];
 [indicator stopAnimating];

does the indicator shows when removing them?

Comment: Have you tried with `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startAnimating:) withObject:indicator waitUntilDone:NO];`?

Comment: Yes I have also tried this but the problem is that I cant send multiple parameter in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u r saying that label added as subview is working on other rows on which U have applied no condition
. Then it may be added to your cell and after reloading the table it disappears . Try your method with some changes :

```
    if (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex==0) 
{
   if ([indexPath row]==[FriendSuggestion count]) 
   {
    int cursor=[Constants getCursorForKey:@"friendList_cursor"];

    if (cursor!=0) 
    {
     [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] addSubview:indicator];
     [indicator setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 25, 37, 37)];
     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startAnimating) toTarget:indicator withObject:nil];


     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self loadingMore:indexPath :indicator :cursor];
     });


    }else
    {
     [tableView reloadData];
     isNoMoreData=YES;
   }
   }
}
```

reload table in else block...

Answer (score 1):

UIKit methods should be performed on the main thread, your loading method should be dispatched not on main thread.

And, maybe to help a little better: WHAT is not working? Errors? Indicator not showing? Crashes?

Start animating your indicator without the NSThread call.

```
[indicator startAnimating];
```

Then create a queue for your loading your data

```
dispatch_queue_t loadingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loading Queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(loadingQueue, ^{
 // loading stuff
}
dispatch_release(loadingQueue);
```

Comment: Yes, I guess its because UIKit manipulation should be performed on the main thread (like animating the indicator or other views)

Comment: Do you see the indicator? Is it just not animating?

Comment: I think I have different problem event label is not adding as subview to my UITableViewCell

Comment: Ok I'm out. I can see no eventLabel in your code. With further questions, please b very more specific, give the piece of code that is relevant and a description of your problem, not simply "is not working"

Comment: Label is also adding and indicator view is also adding but in rows having cell with text != Twenty Five More . This problem is occuring in only last row. Every row is custom cell except last row

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to start the indicator on another thread? Evreyhting with UI should be done on the main thread.

by the way try to add you indicator not to the cell. You must add it to

`cell.contentView`

This is Wrong:

`[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] addSubview:indicator]`

Should Be

`[[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] contentView] addSubview:indicator]`